# False colour coding in an image

Tags: graphics

In latex, a black and white image is inserted, around 90% area of the image is white and 10% black. My supervisor has asked me to use false colour like false:red, wrong: green/blue. There isn't proper info in internet to use this. Could anybody help me out with it?

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\subfloat[Original Depth Image]{
\includegraphics[height=4.0cm,width=7.0cm]{original_depth1.png}
\label{fig:subfigure1}}
```

Thank You

Comment: Just to understand the question: so you want to change the black and white colours from the image to red and green? For this task it might be better to lock into imaging processing software, like e.g. `gimp`. There you can recolour parts based on their original colour.

Comment: yes, i guess. I think it's majorly to change white colour to other @samcarter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the image is saved as a gray-scale image format, then one can change only the intensity/polarity of the black/white.  But if it can be saved in rgb format (I do not mean to change the black/white colors of the image, but only to change to format of the jpeg file in which the image is saved), then the colors themselves can be modified at the time of rendering (see ADDENDUM)

In both cases, the use of the `decodearray` option to `\includegraphics` allows the rendering colors to be changed.  The decode array value of `{1 0 1 0 1 0}` takes the negative of the r, g, and b colors, though other decode arrays can be explored, using decimal values between 0 and 1.  For example, a decode array of `{0 0 0 0 1 .5}` will turn off red and green in the image, and only allow gradations of blue from half to full saturation.

In the MWE below, the actual (unaltered) images are to the left, the false-colored images are to the right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=1in]{example-image-A.jpg}
\includegraphics[width=1in,decodearray={1 0 }]{example-image-A.jpg}

\includegraphics[width=1in]{example-grid-100x100bp.jpg}
\includegraphics[width=1in,decodearray={1 0 1 0 1 0}]{example-grid-100x100bp.jpg}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**

I took a copy of `example-image-A`, a gray-scale rendering (saved in grayscale format), and saved it (still as a gray-scale image) in 3-color rgb format using MS-Paint as `Xexample-image-A`.  Upon so doing, false color rendering is possible:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=1in]{Xexample-image-A}
\includegraphics[width=1in,decodearray={.9 .3 .9 .4 .2 .9 }]{Xexample-image-A}
\end{document}
```

The actual image is to the left, the false-colored image to the right.

[image]