# Invert image colors in latex

Tags: graphics, floats, pdftex, includegraphics

I have figures which I use in several places, some of them in dark context and some of them light (for example, a my obsidian vault is dark but a PDF of my thesis is light). As such, some of the figures are colored to work in a dark environment, and some in light.

But sometimes I want to take a figure from a dark context and use it in a light context, or vice versa. So far I have created a copy of the figure for the light/dark mode by simply inverting the colors. I use color schemes in which this looks mostly fine.

But manually inverting the colors and saving a copy is exhausting, and inefficient. I want to do this automatically, and possibly without saving a copy of the original figure.

**Is there a way to invert the colors of a figure while compiling the output of a latex document?**

Thanks a lot!

Edit: I saw [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34110/is-it-possible-to-invert-substitute-the-colors-of-included-graphics), but the answers were basically "you can't". Since the answers are unsatisfactory and the question is VERY old, I thought it would be best to open a new one. But if this is not the custom here, please let me know and I'll ask there instead.

Comment: I very much doubt that.

Comment: Have you seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29227/can-includegraphics-be-used-to-change-an-image-color/150219#150219 ?

Comment: Here is a usage example of the `decodearray` option: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300334/false-colour-coding-in-an-image/300355#300355

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes this worked perfectly! Want to give that as an answer so I can upvote it and mark it as a solution?

Comment: Might it make more sense to declare this question a duplicate of the other, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300334/false-colour-coding-in-an-image?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes yes, actually it does. Will do.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [sagetex](https://ctan.org/pkg/sagetex) solution along the lines of my answer to [Partial or entire Image Blurring in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295100/partial-or-entire-image-blurring-in-tikz/390470#390470). Python takes care of the inverting the image during the compilation process. The picture is save and then `\sagestr{result1}` puts the text `\includegraphics[width=2in]{MonaInv.png}` into the LaTeX document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
Try this:\\
\includegraphics[width=2in]{Mona.png}
\begin{sagesilent}
from PIL import Image, ImageChops
img = Image.open('Mona.png')
Inv1 = ImageChops.invert(img)
Inv1.save('MonaInv.png')
result1 = r"\includegraphics[width=2in]{MonaInv.png}"
\end{sagesilent}
\sagestr{result1}
\end{document}
```

The result in [Cocalc](https://cocalc.com/) is:
[image]

PIL refers to [Python Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).
The easiest way to experiment this way is with a free Cocalc account.

Comment: Sadly, this is a bit to cumbersome to work for me. Thanks anyway!